# Is there any explanation on how scope of the variable works

Tags: c, scope

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(){

    int a=1, b=2, c=3;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a,b,c );    //1 2 3

    {
        int b=4;
        float c=5.0;

        printf("%d %d %.1f\n", a,b,c);      // 1 4 5.0
        a=b;
        {
            int c;
            c=b;
            printf("%d %d %d\n", a,b,c);        // 4 4 4
        }

         printf("%d %d %.1f\n", a,b,c);        // 4 4 5.0
    }

     printf("%d %d %d\n", a,b,c);              // 4 2 3
}
```

In this code for the last printf statement why is the value of variable a being displayed as 4 in the program even though the value of a has been declared as 1 in this scope?
I mean I understand that that value of a has been assigned to be equal to b, but that is a statement in the inner block of statements. Moreover, even c has been assigned the value of b in one of the inner blocks, but it still retains its value of 3 declared in the outermost block of this code.

Comment: Because `a=b;`. There `a` refers the outer scope `a`.

Comment: Going out of a scope doesn't roll back variable changes. It only destroys variables that were declared in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a1 = 1, b1 = 2, c1 = 3;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a1, b1, c1);  // 1 2 3
    {
        int b2 = 4;
        float c2 = 5.0;
        printf("%d %d %.1f\n", a1, b2, c2);  // 1 4 5.0
        a1 = b2;
        {
            int c3;
            c3 = b2;
            printf("%d %d %d\n", a1, b2, c3);  // 4 4 4
        }
        printf("%d %d %.1f\n", a1, b2, c2);  // 4 4 5.0
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a1, b1, c1);  // 4 2 3
}
```

If a variable is **declared** inside a scope, which means that it has a type like `int a = 5`, then the variable in the outer scope with the same name is shadowed and will no longer be used or affected in the inner scope. However, if a variable is **assigned** inside a scope, meaning that it lacks a type like `a = 5`, and the variable has not been declared inside the scope, then the variable outside the scope will be modified. You can also find [a helpful article here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/).